# C++ std::shared_ptr implementation

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, pointers, c++20

Took a shot at implementing `std::shared_ptr`, with a thread-safe refcount and weak count. Didn't do `weak_ptr`, I'm doing this for learning purposes, and I think from an educational standpoint there's not much to learn from adding it.

Also tried to implement the "we know where you live" optimization, with the control block and the underlying memory allocated together in `makeShared`, but it feels sloppy and error prone and would love advice on if it can be done more cleanly.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class ControlBlock {
public:
    ControlBlock(): 
        m_ptr{nullptr},
        m_ref_count{0}, 
        m_weak_count{0}
    {}

    ControlBlock(T* ptr): 
        m_ptr{ptr},
        m_ref_count{1}, 
        m_weak_count{0}
    {}

    void add_reference() {
        m_ref_count.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }

    void add_weak_reference() {
        m_weak_count.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }

    void remove_reference() {
        // The release memory barrier ensures all operations on this thread are 
        // visible to other threads before a decrement happens 
        if (m_ref_count.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release) == 1) {
            // the acquire memory barrier makes sure we delete the pointer 
            // and control block only after the ref count has gone to 0

            std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
            m_ptr->~T();

            if (m_weak_count.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 0) {
                delete this;
            }
        }
    }

    void remove_weak_reference() {
        if (m_weak_count.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release) == 1) {
            std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
            if (m_ref_count.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 0) {
                delete this;
            }
        }
    }

    T* get() const noexcept {
        return m_ptr;
    }

    std::size_t use_count() const noexcept {
        return m_ref_count.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }

    std::size_t weak_count() const noexcept {
        return m_weak_count.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    static ControlBlock* create (Args&&... args) {
        std::size_t cb_size = sizeof(ControlBlock);
        std::size_t t_size = sizeof(T);

        std::size_t t_alignment = alignof(T);
        std::size_t remainder = cb_size % t_alignment; 
        std::size_t padding = remainder ? (t_alignment - remainder) : 0;
        std::size_t t_offset = cb_size + padding; 

        char* chunk = static_cast<char*>(::operator new(cb_size + t_size));

        T* ptr = nullptr;
        try {
            ptr = new (chunk + t_offset) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        } catch (...) {
            ::operator delete (chunk);
            throw;
        }

        try {
            return new(chunk) ControlBlock{ptr};
        } catch(...) {
            ptr->~T();
            ::operator delete(chunk);
            throw;
        }
    }

private:
    T* m_ptr; 

    std::atomic<std::size_t> m_ref_count;
    std::atomic<std::size_t> m_weak_count;
};

template<typename T>
class SharedPtr {
public:
    SharedPtr() noexcept : cb{new ControlBlock<T>()} {}
    SharedPtr(T* item) : cb{new ControlBlock<T>{item}} {}

    template<typename U>
    requires(std::is_convertible_v<U*, T*>)
    SharedPtr(SharedPtr<U>&& other) noexcept 
        : SharedPtr{other.cb}
    {
        other.cb = nullptr;
    }

    SharedPtr(const SharedPtr& other) : cb{other.cb} {
        cb->add_reference();
    }

    SharedPtr (SharedPtr&& other) : cb{other.cb} {
        other.cb = nullptr;
    }

    SharedPtr& operator=(const SharedPtr& other) {
        if (this == &other) return *this;

        SharedPtr temp{other};
        swap(temp);
        return *this;
    }

    SharedPtr& operator=(SharedPtr&& other) {
        if (this == &other) return *this;

        SharedPtr temp{std::move(other)};
        swap(temp);
        return *this;
    }

    int use_count() const noexcept {
        return cb -> use_count();
    }

    void swap(SharedPtr& other) noexcept {
        std::swap(cb, other.cb);
    }

    T* reset() {
        T* result = get();
        SharedPtr new_ptr;
        swap(new_ptr);

        return result;
    }

    T* reset(T* new_val) {
        T* result = get();

        SharedPtr new_ptr{new_val};
        swap(new_ptr);

        return result;
    }

    T* get() const noexcept {
        return cb->get();
    }

    T& operator*() const {
        return *get();
    }

    T* operator->() const noexcept {
        return get();
    }

    explicit operator bool() const noexcept {
        return get() != nullptr;
    }

    ~SharedPtr() {
        if (cb) {
            cb -> remove_reference();
        }   
    }
private:
    ControlBlock<T>* cb;
    
    // Make all specializations of SharedPtr friends
    // with one another
    template<typename U>
    friend class SharedPtr;

    // Make makeShared a friend of the SharedPtr class
    // so we can use the private ControlBlock constructor
    template<typename U, typename...Args>
    friend SharedPtr<U> makeShared(Args&&... args);

    SharedPtr(ControlBlock<T>* cb) : cb{cb} {}

    template <typename U>
    SharedPtr(ControlBlock<U>* cb) :
        cb{reinterpret_cast<ControlBlock<T>*>(cb)} {}
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
SharedPtr<T> makeShared(Args&&... args) {
    auto cb = ControlBlock<T>::create(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return SharedPtr<T>{cb};
}
```

Added some unit tests as well, based on the example behavior on cppreference, but again would love some advice on how to really stress test this, especially since the control block creation is so manual and error prone.

````
// Have to define the test module first, always.
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE sharedptrtest

#ifdef BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#   include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#else
#   include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#endif // BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK

#include <boost/test/data/test_case.hpp>
#include <boost/test/data/monomorphic.hpp>

#include "SharedPtr.h"

struct Foo {
    int id{0};
    Foo (int i = 0) : id{i} {}
    ~Foo() = default;

    int val() {
        return id;
    }
};

struct B
{
    virtual ~B() = default; 
    virtual int val() const {return 0;}
};
 
struct D : B
{
    D() { }
    ~D() {}
 
    int val() const override {
        return 2;
    }
};


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(default_constructor_test)
{
    {
        SharedPtr<Foo> s1;
    }   
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(runtime_poly)
{
    SharedPtr<B> p = makeShared<D>();
    assert(p -> val() == 2);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(copy_constructor_test)
{
    SharedPtr<Foo> s1(new Foo{10});
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s1.use_count(),  1);
    {
        SharedPtr<Foo> s2{s1}; 
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s1.use_count(),  2);
    }

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s1.use_count(),  1);   
}


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(copy_assigment_test)
{
    SharedPtr<Foo> s1(new Foo{10});
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s1.use_count(), 1);
    {
        SharedPtr<Foo> s2 = s1; 
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s1.use_count(), 2);
    }

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s1.use_count(), 1);   
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(move_assigment_test)
{
    SharedPtr<Foo> s1(new Foo{10});
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s1.use_count(), 1);

    SharedPtr<Foo> s2 = std::move(s1); 
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s2.use_count(), 1);   
}


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(reset_test)
{
    SharedPtr<Foo> s1(new Foo{10});
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s1->val(), 10);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s1.use_count(), 1);

    s1.reset(new Foo{20});
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s1->val(), 20);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s1.use_count(), 1);
    
    s1.reset();
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s1.use_count(), 0);
}


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(swap_test)
{
    SharedPtr<Foo> s1 = makeShared<Foo>(100);
    SharedPtr<Foo> s2 = makeShared<Foo>(200);

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s1->val(), 100);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s2->val(), 200);

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s1.use_count(), 1);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s1.use_count(), 1);

    s1.swap(s2);

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s1->val(), 200);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s2->val(), 100);

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s1.use_count(), 1);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s1.use_count(), 1);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(get_and_deref_test)
{
    int* pInt = new int{42};
    SharedPtr shInt = makeShared<int>(42);

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(*pInt, *shInt);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(*pInt, *(shInt.get()));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(bool_test)
{
    SharedPtr<int> ptr;
    BOOST_CHECK(!(static_cast<bool>(ptr)));

    ptr = makeShared<int>(7);
    BOOST_CHECK((static_cast<bool>(ptr)));
}
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Make `ControlBlock`'s constructors `noexcept`

The constructors of `ControlBlock` are very trivial and never throw an exception, so mark these constructors `noexcept`. That then greatly simplifies `create()`, where you now only need one `try`-`catch` block:

```
try {
    T *ptr = new (chunk + t_offset) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return new(chunk) ControlBlock{ptr};
} catch (...) {
    ::operator delete (chunk);
    throw;
}
```

## Incorrect handling of alignment restrictions

There are two obvious mistakes in handling the alignment of `T` in `create()`:

1. You don't reserve any memory for the `padding`.
2. You calculate the offset before you even know what address `chunk` will point to.

You should first allocate `cb_size + t_size + t_alignment` bytes. Then once you have the pointer to that allocation, you can check how much you have to add to `chunk + cb_size` to get an address that is correctly aligned for `T`.

## Missing deletion of `T`

Unless you created the `ControlBlock` and the `T` object in one allocation, then there is a `delete m_ptr` missing. Note that you have to be careful to not both call `m_ptr->~T()` and `delete m_ptr` in that case.

## Unnecessary checks for self-assignment

You added checks for self-(move)-assignment and early out in those cases. But without these checks, your code is still correct, thanks to the fact that you have used the copy-and-swap idiom. You might do more work than necessary if you do a self-assignment, but consider that it is very unlikely that someone assigns an object to itself, and you actually slightly reduce the performance of the normal case.

## The move-assignment operator can be made `noexcept`

Since the move-assignment operator just does a move-construction and a swap, both of which are `noexcept`, the move-assignment operator itself can also be made `noexcept`.

## Assignment operators should also be templates

For the same reason you made the move constructor a template, the assignment operators should also be templates, with the same `requires` clause.

## Missing some functionality

> Didn't do `weak_ptr`, I'm doing this for learning purposes, and I think from an educational standpoint there's not much to learn from adding it.

I think you are wrong about that. Implementing all the member functions of [`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) correctly is perhaps not rocket science, but you don't know about all the corner cases you might have to handle until you try it. Also consider that without it, you can't actually test correct handling of weak references in your test suite.

There is also other functionality missing that is in [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), like support for arrays, `owner_before()`, the member types `element_type` and `weak_type`, other non-member functions that work with `std::shared_ptr`, `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr>`, support for custom allocators and deleters, constructors/assignment operators that take a `std::unique_ptr` as argument, and more.

## Add unit tests for `ControlBlock` as well

In addition to testing `SharedPtr`, you should add unit tests for `ControlBlock` as well, just to make sure the internals of your code are also working as you, the developer, are expecting.

Comment: Thanks @G. Sliepen for the help! 

On having converting assignment operators, I still need to keep the non-converting ones around, right? Because if I don't, the compiler tries to match against a non-converting assignment operator which is marked as deleted because I declared a converting assignment.

Comment: Also I'm not quite following how the variant of `::operator new` that does the alignment for me is supposed to simplify things. If I do something like:

`char* chunk = static_cast<char*>(::operator new(sizeof(T) + sizeof(ControlBlock)), std::align_val_t(sizeof(T)));`

Then won't I still have issues with getting ControlBlock aligned, even though T is now aligned? Or do we just assume ControlBlock has less strict requirements than T for alignment, so this should be fine? Or should I be using this operator some other way? Thanks!

Comment: Hm you are right that you also have to check the alignment of the `ControlBlock` in that case, I was only thinking about over-aligned `T`s, but if you have a `SharedPtr<bool>` then you need to have padding between the `bool` and the `ControlBlock`.

Answer (score 4):

### There are Numerous Bugs.

#### First, the Converting Move Constructor

The deleter calls the decrement member function of the control block of `ControlBlock`, which calls `m_ptr->~T();`.  And the converting constructors to make a `SharedPtr<T>` from a `SharedPtr<U>` create a `ControlBlock<T>`.  This means that `~T()` will be called instead of `~U()`, which will fail unless `U` inherits a `virtual` destructor from `T`.

However, the Standard ([util.smartptr.shared.const]) specifies that this will also work for static, not dynamic, inheritance.  Additionally, a cast to a `virtual` base class pointer might have a different object representation from the original pointer.

Another bug, at least if you meant this to do what the Standard specifies, is that the converting constructor creates a new control block with its own reference count, instead of sharing the reference count.

And this creates a serious memory-safety bug!  Let's take a look at this constructor:

```cpp
    template<typename U>
    requires(std::is_convertible_v<U*, T*>)
    SharedPtr(SharedPtr<U>&& other) noexcept 
        : SharedPtr{other.cb}
    {
        other.cb = nullptr;
    }
```

This calls the following constructor:

```cpp
    ControlBlock(T* ptr): 
        m_ptr{ptr},
        m_ref_count{1}, 
        m_weak_count{0}
    {}
```

Which makes a shallow copy of the pointer with its own reference count of 1.

But we only checked that `other` was a rvalue reference—not that it was the *last* reference to its memory!  When it isn’t we now have *two* control blocks that both will try to delete the *same* pointer.  Memory-corruption bug!  Simple example:

```cpp
void foo(SharedPtr<SomeClass>&&);

void bar() {
    SharedPtr<SomeCompatibleClass> p(new SomeCompatibleClass);
    // We still need p afterward, but foo consumes its input. So, pass it a copy!
    foo(std::move(SharedPtr<SomeCompatibleClass>(p)));
    // Why am I getting heap-corruption bugs from here on out?
}
```

What does this code do?  It’s trying to call `foo(p)`, which expects a `SharedPtr<SomeClass>&&`, with a `SharedPtr<SomeCompatibleClass>&&`.  We’re moving from a copy of the `SharedPtr` with a reference count of 2, so as not to destroy the original `p`.

To resolve the overload, the compiler looks for and finds a template constructor that works out to `SharedPtr<SomeClass>(SharedPtr<SomeCompatibleClass>&&)`.  It creates a temporary `SharedPtr<SomeClass>` with its own control block and reference count of 1.  When `foo` returns, the lifetime of this temporary expires.  *Its destructor frees the `SomeClass` while another shared pointer to it is still alive.*  The destructor of `p` gets called when `bar` returns—freeing its `m_ptr` a second time.  Whoops!

#### The Thread-Safety is Also Not Correct

You frequently perform multiple loads or updates on individual data members but depend on them being consistent.  For example, your decrement function has this snippet of code:

```cpp
    void remove_weak_reference() {
        if (m_weak_count.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release) == 1) {
            std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
            if (m_ref_count.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 0) {
                delete this;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is not thread-safe!  Both individual operations are atomic, but they’re *separate* operations that might return inconsistent values.  For example, if the thread that decrements `ref_count` and the thread that decrements `weak_count` see the older values of the other count, neither thread will ever see both equal to 0, causing a memory leak.

What you need to do is retrieve and update both counts in *the same* atomic operation.  You also want this operation to be a lock-free atomic compare-and-swap.  On variants of x86 that support the `cmpxchg16b` instruction, mainstream compilers will generate it *if* you tell it to support a recent-enough instruction set, *and* if you pack the control block into a 16-byte `struct` or `class` declared with `alignas(16)`.  I would suggest, however, that you test for this at compile time, using something like (adjust this to work on your implementation):

```cpp
    static_assert( std::atomic<ControlBlock<void>>::is_always_lock_free,
                   "ControlBlock does not support lock-free atomic operations with these compiler settings." );
```

Since it’s likely that your final implementation will need to be larger than 16 bytes, consider atomically fetching and updating just a `struct` or bitfield containing the two reference counts, which can be eight bytes long.  On many architectures, this can use ordinary 64-bit instructions.

You absolutely want to avoid the overhead of mutex locking on every single operation!

### Block Allocation Looks More Complex than it Needs to Be

The `new` operator already aligns memory correctly for the type it’s allocating, so I’m not sure why there’s so much low-level stuff in `ControlBlock<T>::create()`.  If you do need low-level allocation of aligned memory, use `std::aligned_alloc`.

### You Will Need a Different Approach to Support the Missing Features

You probably left them out for simplicity, but some of them would require significant redesigns to add later.  These include:

- Each `SharedPtr<T>` cannot reference a `ControlBlock<T>` if reference counts are to be correctly shared with a `SharedPtr<U>`.  You either want there to be a single `ControlBlock` class, or an abstract base class `ControlBlock<Deleter>`.
- Therefore, `m_ptr` should be moved into the `shared_ptr` instances.  This also speeds up access to it and enables you to support pointer conversions that change the pointer’s object representation, or `std::dynamic_ptr_cast`.
- If you support `std::get_deleter`, you’ll need to store the deleter in the control block and remember its type, so you will want each `ControlBlock<Deleter>` to inherit from the same abstract base class.  If retrieving the deleter is unnecessary, you can get by with a single `ControlBlock` class that stores the deleter in a `std::function<void()>` with `[[no_unique_address]]`.
- Therefore, a `ControlBlock` cannot in the general case be small enough to have a lock-free, thread-safe implementation, and you will need to declare some other atomic type to read and update both counts in the *same* atomic operation.
- If you want to support [`std::get_deleter<Deleter, T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get_deleter), it will be very helpful to have a helper function `virtual void* ControlBlock::get_deleter_helper(const std::type_info&& dtype) const noexcept`, called from `static_cast<Deleter<T>*>(p.cb->get_deleter_helper(typeid(Deleter<T>)))`.

Comment: Very good points about the deleter and the thread-safety of `remove_weak_reference()`. About the block allocation being complicated: it's necessary to get the correct alignment that way, as the allocation of storage is done using a direct call to `::operator new()`, which only does basic alignment. The `T` object is created using placement new, which doesn't align anything for you. You can't use `std::aligned_alloc()`  to align the `T` when the allocated region starts with a `ControlBlock`. It would be possible if the `T` object came first and then would be followed by the `ControlBlock`.

Comment: @G.Sliepen OP would need to abandon the idea of a single allocation for both `T` and `ControlBlock<T>` to support custom deleters anyway. With the current interface, using `ControlBlock<T>`, the control block could just contain the `T` itself, as a data member. It will then have the correct alignment and the compiler will calculate any necessary padding silently. Much simpler than what the code sample is doing now and just as powerful.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks for the help! I had a few questions: 

You mentioned the converting move constructor calls the ControlBlock constructor and creates a separate ref count, which is obviously a problem, but I don't see this happening. The SharedPtr class holds a pointer to the ControlBlock class, not an instance of it, so there's no reason for the constructor to get called, and I put in some print statements and I don't see it called more than once for the following code: 

    `SharedPtr<D> d = makeShared<D>();`
    `SharedPtr<B> p = std::move(d);`

Comment: So the question is, what am I missing? How can I reproduce the behavior you suggest is happening?

Comment: Also regarding thread safety, I am new to understanding atomics and memory barriers in C++. But my goal is that even though there are two separate atomic operations, the memory barriers should keep this thread safe. When I do a `fetch_sub` with a `release` barrier, I ensure all other threads see my previous operations before seeing the decrement. Then the `acquire` fence ensures I see all updates from other threads before deleting the pointer. Why don't these operations together provide thread safety? What am I missing in my understanding of these barriers? Thanks again!

Comment: @jdav22 No, the memory barriers don’t prevent one thread reading the `ref_count` before the other thread decrements it, then decrementing the `weak_count` after the other thread reads it. In fact, the memory barrier inserting a pause between reading the `ref_count` and writing the `weak_count` makes that bug *more* likely to happen.

Comment: @jdav22 Memory barriers can ensure that threads see each all writes from each other in the same orde. But here, what you need is to ensure that one and  only one thread will see both counts equal to zero. A lock-free operation for that is an atomic copy-and-swap. It’s such an important operation, modern CPUs are designed to make it fast.

Comment: @jdav22 If, for instance, you were adding a message to the end of a queue, acquire/release memory ordering could guarantee that, if the other thread sees that a message has been posted, it will also see the updated message data that the same thread wrote before it posted the message. But that’s not the case here.

Comment: Will briefly note that there are other solutions than the ones I posted here. A common solution to thread-safety is to maintain a *total* count of references and a *strong* count, and always access them in the correct order.

Comment: You could also implement `get_deleter` by storing the deleter in a `std::function` and calling its `target()` method. Thanks to other contributors who’ve given feedback and corrections!